# Computer to multiple arduino bluetooth modules

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano

Im going to take part in a competition called IEEE Very Small Soccer and I need to set up a communication between my computer, that will run visual and strategy algorithms, and send some commands to 3 Arduinos, which will be the players. Most people use the Xbee module to send data to the Arduinos, so I was wondering why not use the Bluetooth module instead, once it is so much cheaper and the difference in power consumption isn't so big, the only drawback would be the working range, which is 10m, if Im correct... However, if the distance is really 10m, not 5m It will be ok, because the computer is always close to the robots.

Summing up, my questions are:

1. Can I use a computer to send data to 3 Arduinos at the same time?
2. What is the real working range of the Bluetooth module?
3. Any suggestions or tips? =D

[image: IEEE Very Small Size Soccer schematic]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes, you can, this is what happens normally in a crowded area where multiple people use their phones with bluetooth headsets, for example.
2. if you believe [the claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) typical 10m max 100m but in practice there are a number of factors:

   - Quality of the HW design of the antennas
   - Signal to noise ratio due to other radios operating in the same area
   - Obstacles in the path
   - Responsiveness and throughput required by your application
   - etc.
3. you could consider other options, like [this module](http://hallard.me/nrf24l01-real-life-range-test/), which is basically the same, from the perspective of transferring data. Also [wifi](http://www.esp8266.com/) could work, if you are allowed to setup your own access point.